# Tool for editing and manipulation JSON?

Tags: json, editor

JSON is very popular among social network sites.

I have been searching tools for analyzing JSON and found some good tools for viewing but they do not meet my needs. (like http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/)

I need to search and filter the data by specific a field and then get some value from another specific field.

Can you suggest a tool or a way to view my JSON data easily?

sample data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "141816652602643",
      "from": {
        "name": "Deval Agrifarman",
        "id": "896085636"
      },
      "message": "yang belum bisa berhenti ngerokok silahkan dilihat... kalo ga bisa donlot mampir aja ke rumah bawa camilan :D",
      "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQC3wb7_yd8fdv64&w=130&h=130&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi1.ytimg.com\u00252Fvi\u00252FDiyWK3fzTpA\u00252Fhqdefault.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiyWK3fzTpA",
      "name": "Sex, Lies & Cigarettes': Vanguard Sneak Peek (Indonesia Subtitle-Full)",
      "description": "Fakta mengenai Industri dan bisnis Rokok diIndonesia, Penetrasi Rokok dalam masyarakat Indonesia.. Dalam Konferensi Dunia untuk Tembakau 2010 Koresponden Chr...",
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
      "created_time": "2012-01-26T15:03:21+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "109379672518544",
      "from": {
        "name": "Deval Agrifarman",
        "id": "896085636"
      },
      "message": "kesannya kok kayak aku yang minta ke monyet nya yah wkwkwkwk...",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=107424555941677&set=a.101882006495932.4636.100000224005368&type=1",
      "name": "~KeBaB~",
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
      "created_time": "2012-01-23T15:33:45+0000",
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_32659",
            "from": {
              "name": "Dhanank Perdhana",
              "id": "1243815675"
            },
            "message": "Deval: \"Mbah, tolong diramal dong garis tangan saya...\"\nMbak Nyemot: \"Hooo.. kamu ini ngga' cocok jadi pejabat.. Nanti kamu pasti pengen cepet2 beli Bentley.. \"\n\n...huehuehue... :P",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-23T15:39:34+0000",
            "likes": 3,
            "user_likes": true
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_32663",
            "from": {
              "name": "Alex Zar",
              "id": "1378608838"
            },
            "message": "klo sodara mmg harus saling berbagi...",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-23T15:42:19+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_32682",
            "from": {
              "name": "Deval Agrifarman",
              "id": "896085636"
            },
            "message": "Dhanank Perdhana baiklah mbah aku akan jadi pejabat saja... biar punya jaguar... xixixi...\n\nAlex Zar weleh... sodara mu toh? kirain syapa :D xixixi...",
            "message_tags": [
              {
                "id": "1243815675",
                "name": "Dhanank Perdhana",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 16
              },
              {
                "id": "1378608838",
                "name": "Alex Zar",
                "offset": 92,
                "length": 8
              }
            ],
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-23T15:46:13+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_33010",
            "from": {
              "name": "Ali M. Fauzi",
              "id": "1248947710"
            },
            "message": "\"Seharusnya tangan diatas lebih baik dari tangan dibawah.\" Kira2 klo kondisinya kayak gitu gmn ya? :-) :)",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-23T17:11:03+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_33012",
            "from": {
              "name": "Ali M. Fauzi",
              "id": "1248947710"
            },
            "message": "\"Seharusnya tangan diatas lebih baik dari tangan dibawah.\" Kira2 klo kondisinya kayak gitu gmn ya? :-) :)",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-23T17:11:17+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_34880",
            "from": {
              "name": "Deval Agrifarman",
              "id": "896085636"
            },
            "message": "kesannya kayak DPR sekarang... tangannya di atas tapi nyolong dari yang ada di bawah... :D wkwkwkwk...",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-24T03:07:16+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_35753",
            "from": {
              "name": "Maruko Chan",
              "id": "100001798922313"
            },
            "message": "LOL! iya.. hahaha",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-24T09:14:24+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_38576",
            "from": {
              "name": "Y.i. Kusumawati",
              "id": "1334087290"
            },
            "message": "sbenernya monyetnya yang mana",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-25T00:01:56+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_39568",
            "from": {
              "name": "Ali M. Fauzi",
              "id": "1248947710"
            },
            "message": "Nah.... Loh... pertanyaan bagus tuh....",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-25T06:10:11+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "109379672518544_39665",
            "from": {
              "name": "Ajungo Toriyama",
              "id": "1266357019"
            },
            "message": "Deval Agrifarman : salim dulu....sama kakak.....",
            "message_tags": [
              {
                "id": "896085636",
                "name": "Deval Agrifarman",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 16
              }
            ],
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-25T07:13:39+0000"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/109379672518544/comments?limit=25&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&callback=___GraphExplorerAsyncCallback___&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAKn8Nfv307rHgjdP9l9usbDj1KbQlzotoQDs6zuQEcxioPm73R3h1ZABBiNQyPG9iukYZAxjnxwmd6ZCNuYdkkKQ7KA4QZDZD&offset=25&__after_id=109379672518544_39665"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "335701516450154",
      "from": {
        "name": "Deval Agrifarman",
        "id": "896085636"
      },
      "message": "selamat tahun baru lagi yah :D sori nggak sempet bikin kartu ucapan :)",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150484907061432&set=a.170757796431.134250.152798801431&type=1",
      "name": "Wall Photos",
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
      "created_time": "2012-01-23T11:36:19+0000"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/896085636/links?limit=3&format=json&since=1327590201&__paging_token=141816652602643&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/896085636/links?limit=3&format=json&until=1327318579&__paging_token=335701516450154"
  }
}
```

what i need is for example:

- getting values of 'link' from 'created_time' in january
- getting values of 'message' and 'picture' plus all 'name' and 'message' inside 'comments' if there are any

Comment: What JSON data are you using?  Maybe provide an example.  How are you retrieving this data from the 'social networking site'?  What do you want to do with the data once you've extracted it from the JSON file?

Comment: @MikeSteder i retrieve them manually (using graph api explorer) any other suggestion is welcome. i just want do some query with them (like additional information mentioned above)

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use this tool http://codedestine.com/json-editor.html It has feature to add date and its drag and drop UI makes it easy to construct json. It will show you json in object view, then you can select any node and get its data and even can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If Java tools are OK, look at [JSONPath](http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/), article http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

> Data may be interactively found and extracted out of JSON structures on the client without special scripting.

Answer (score 0):

There is also JSONselect http://jsonselect.org/#tryit I have found today.

```
JSONSelect is an experimental selector language for JSON.

It makes it easy to access data in complex JSON documents.

It feels like CSS.
```

Code on GitHub https://github.com/lloyd/JSONSelect
Last updated    a year ago